# How can we use MS Edge to click a button in a browser?

Tags: excel, vba

As I know, IE Explorer is pretty much depreciated now, so I am trying to use MS Edge to open a browser and click a couple of buttons on a web page. I can open the page with this.

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "microsoft-edge:http://edd/Reports/powerbi/Power%Test%Lab"
```

How can I click a button named in Edge that has this behind it?

`<a role="button href="pbi-desktop"><span id="nav-pbi-edit" class="text">Edit in Power BI</span>`

Then, a button with an ID of 'Cancel' opens. I would like to click that, if it's possible. Are these two tasks doable in MS Edge?

Comment: You need to use Selenium

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know!